# how to set application name with line break?

Tags: java, android

how is it possible to make a line break for the application title? I would like to have the name on two lines under the icon amongst the installed programs on phone, like:
Harry's
App

In the xml file, setting the app_name pretty much returns a one-line title, or cuts it when the end of space is reached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\n` for a line break in your XML. You can use `<br>` too, but Eclipse might pop that up as a problem

Comment: Did not work for me in Android 6. Any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

`\n` didn't work for me `\r\n` did the trick